# Notepad ++ document labelled utf-16 but has utf-8 content

Tags: xsd

I get this error message'document labelled utf-16 but has utf-8 content' when i validate my xsd in notepad ++. What could be the cause ? Here is my xsd :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" version="1.0" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="Member">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="Request">
          <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:element name="Transaction">
                <xsd:complexType>
                  <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="Number" type="xsd:int" />
                    <xsd:element name="DateTime" type="xsd:decimal" />
                    <xsd:element name="TestIndicator" type="xsd:string" />
                  </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
              </xsd:element>
              <xsd:element name="Membership">
                <xsd:complexType>
                  <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="MembershipNumber" type="xsd:int" />
                  </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
              </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
          </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
      </xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:attribute name="xs:schemaLocation" type="xsd:string" />
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Comment: It's not about the XSD but about your XML file: it is UTF-8.

Comment: @SimeonVisser So how can i solve this problem ?

Comment: How do i make notepad ++ validate this xsd successfully?

Answer (score 1):

Change the encoding line to read utf-8 instead of utf-16 (very top of your xml file).

Comment: If i change it to utf-8 i get 'Unable to parse scheme file' error message

Comment: I have used this site to generate my xsd : http://www.xmlforasp.net/CodeBank/System_Xml_Schema/BuildSchema/BuildXMLSchema.aspx. Do you perhaps know of a site that will help me generate xsd without any error messages ?

Comment: @chosenOneThabs: you can only fix it by knowing the encoding of the file. Otherwise you're going to get errors.

Comment: @SimeonVisser how do i check the encoding of the file ?

Comment: @chosenOneThabs: Notepad++ should have a file properties dialog or some other location where you can read that.

Comment: @SimeonVisser I can't find an option to view properties. How do you solve this kind of issue ? What tool do you use to generate xsd file?

Comment: Notepad++ has an "encoding" menu.  That menu has functions to convert the file.  Hopefully that will help?  Specifically "Convert to UTF8" should be useful.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug open in Notepad++ issues tracker for something similar: https://sourceforge.net/p/npp-plugins/bugs/166/

May be your file has an encoding which match the header but the XML plugin shows an inappropriate error.

Check if Notepad++ show UCS-2 in its status bar (UTF-16 is an extension of UCS-2). If it's there, you are OK because there is only ASCII 7 bit characters in your file apparently.